# Highcharts MVC Unable to get value of the property 'series': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am trying to run this example of Highcharts in IE9

http://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server.htm

but instead of calling the php script i am doing the following:

```
function requestData() {            
        var MyAppUrlSettings = {
            MyUsefulUrl: '/PaymentConfirmation/UpdateChart?numSecondsToGoBack=3600'
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: MyAppUrlSettings.MyUsefulUrl,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (PaymentConfirmationData) {
                $.each(PaymentConfirmationData, function (i, PaymentConfirmation) {

                    var d = new Date(); 
                    d.setTime(parseInt(PaymentConfirmation.TimeMilliSeconds));                            
                    var milli = d.getTime();
                    var series = chart.series[0],
                 shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20
                    // add the point
                    chart.series[0].addPoint([milli, PaymentConfirmation.Count], true, shift);

                    // call it again after one second
                    setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("An AJAX error occured: " + status + "\nError: " + error);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

Now like in the example the chart object is declared globally (and i think that is somehow not working!!!)

Note: the "$(document).ready(function() {" function is as it is in the example.

Please help and thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual chart code here is my best guess. You did not define your series object correctly. This line is the issue I think:

```
var series = chart.series[0],
```

I believe that should be a `;` instead of a `,`.

Also, if you still get this error then you created a `chart` with no `series` but then try to push a point to a `series[0]`. Make sure you create an empty series (or create a `series` after `chart` creation). Like in the example page given:

```
series: [{
     name: 'Random data',
     data: []
   }]
```

Comment: Well the comma (,) is because there is another var declared (shift) in the line below (that's the original code). Also i now tried having all me functions inside of jquery ready block and it now works. I am still confused as the example in as it is mode doesn't work for me. Thanks anyways wergeld...its wierd really (and i am sure i am missing something!).